# How to generate GraphQL query from protocol buffer generated code with gqlgen?

Tags: go, graphql, grpc-go, gqlgen

I have a protocol buffer file which includes an enumeration within a message.

```
message Advisor {
  ...
  enum AdvisorRole {
    // here be values
  }
}
```

This pb is the input to generate stubs using `protoc-gen-gogo`.

```
../gen/ProjectService.pb.go

type Advisor_AdvisorRole int32
const (
    // here be constant values
  )
```

The generated code is in time referenced from the `.gqlgen.yaml` to configure the gql service code generation.

```
models:
...
  AdvisorRole:
    model: github.com/.../gen/pb.Advisor_AdvisorRole
```

Finally when execute `go generate ./...` the type does not exist in the execution context.

```
C:\Users\...\gql\generated.go:40578:12: ec._AdvisorRole undefined (type *executionContext has no field or method _AdvisorRole)
```

I have tried taking out the enumeration from the message and updated the reference in the configuration file, but that did not make any difference.